# How can I fix the metaclass conflict in django-rest-framework Serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I've written the following code in django and DRF:

```py
class ServiceModelMetaClass(serializers.SerializerMetaclass, type):
    SERVICE_MODELS = {
        "email": EmailSubscriber,
        "push": PushSubscriber
    }

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        service = kwargs.get("data", {}).get("service")
        cls.Meta.subscriber_model = cls.SERVICE_MODELS.get(service)
        return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)


class InterListsActionsSerializer(serializers.Serializer, metaclass=ServiceModelMetaClass):
    source_list_id = serializers.IntegerField()
    target_list_id = serializers.IntegerField()
    subscriber_ids = serializers.IntegerField(many=True, required=False)
    account_id = serializers.CharField()
    service = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=("email", "push"))

    class Meta:
        subscriber_model: Model = None

    def move(self):
        model = self.Meta.subscriber_model
        # Rest of the method code.
```

The purpose of this code is that this serializer might need doing operation on different models based on the service that the user wants to use. So I wrote this metaclass to prevent writing duplicate code and simply change the `subscriber_model` based on user's needs.
Now as you might know, `serializers.Serializer` uses a metaclass by its own, `serializers.SerializerMetaclass`. If I don't use this metaclass for creating my metaclass, it results in the following error:
`TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases.`
But when I try making my `ServiceModelMetaClass` metaclass to inherit from `serializers.SerializerMetaclass` it gives me this error:

```
   File "/project-root/segment_management/serializers/subscriber_list.py", line 33, in <module>
    class InterListsActionsSerializer(serializers.Serializer, metaclass=ServiceModelMetaClass):
  File "/project-root/segment_management/serializers/subscriber_list.py", line 36, in InterListsActionsSerializer
    subscriber_ids = serializers.IntegerField(many=True, required=False)
  File "/project-root/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py", line 894, in __init__
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
TypeError: Field.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'many'
```

What should I do to fix this problem or maybe a better alternative approach that keeps the code clean without using metaclass? Thanks in advance.

Comment: it does not look like this is the metaclass that introduces the problem, but the `many=True` of your `IntegerField`.

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem Yes, removing many=True fixes the problem. But how can I fix that? I need to use many=True.

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem Thanks for the insight. I tried using `ListField` with `IntegerField()` as child and it fixed the error. I thought all the fields can accept `many` but apparently the don't.

Comment: normally yes, then it constructs a `ListField` itself, I'm actually surprised as well.

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem I think you should post your comment as an answer so I can mark it as correct.

Comment: @Adralan: ah, I looked it up, this is something a serializer does, but not a field itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not the metaclass, or at least it is not the primary problem. The main problem is the `many=True` for your `IntegerField`. I looked it up, and apparently a field can not have `many=True`, only a `Serializer` can. Indeed, if we inspect the [source code, we see <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/41edb3b9dde2105b9fb015ce6b8171e7822baa30/rest_framework/serializers.py#L120-L125):

> ```
> def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
>     # We override this method in order to automatically create
>     # `ListSerializer` classes instead when `many=True` is set.
>     if kwargs.pop('many', False):
>         return cls.many_init(*args, **kwargs)
>     return super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
> ```

and the `.many_init(…)` essentially creates the field as a child field, and [wraps it in a `ListSerializer` <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/41edb3b9dde2105b9fb015ce6b8171e7822baa30/rest_framework/serializers.py#L131-L167):

> ```
> @classmethod def many_init(cls, *args, **kwargs):
>     # …
>     child_serializer = cls(*args, **kwargs)
>     list_kwargs = {
>         'child': child_serializer,
>     }
>     # …
>     meta = getattr(cls, 'Meta', None)
>     list_serializer_class = getattr(meta, 'list_serializer_class', ListSerializer)
>     return list_serializer_class(*args, **list_kwargs)
> ```

But we can appy essentially the same trick with a field, by using a [**`ListField`** <sup>[drf-doc]</sup>](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#listfield):

```
class InterListsActionsSerializer(
    serializers.Serializer, metaclass=ServiceModelMetaClass
):
    source_list_id = serializers.IntegerField()
    target_list_id = serializers.IntegerField()
    subscriber_ids = serializers.ListField(
        child=serializers.IntegerField(), required=False
    )
    account_id = serializers.CharField()
    service = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=('email', 'push'))

    class Meta:
        subscriber_model: Model = None

    def move(self):
        model = self.Meta.subscriber_model
```